# Why one-sided-error equality problem communication complexity is at least O(n)

Tags: communication-complexity

I'm trying to solve an exercise from "*Algorithmics for hard problems*" but I have no idea how to solve it. First the definition of one-sided-error Monte Carlo algorithm is a little different than usual. We say A is a one-sided error monte carlo algorithm recognizing L if

1. for every $x \in L, Prob(A(x)=1) \geq1/2$
2. for every $x \notin L, Prob(A(x)=0) =1$
   so the side of error is determined. The exercise asks to prove that every one-sided-error monte carlo one-way protocol that computes *Equality* must have a communication complexity of at least n.